# inverted sentence starts with 'Of'

Tags: prepositions

I read a sentence I couldn't understand:

"Of less frequent and perhaps unique deviations from the standard patterns, the variety is almost endless."

I know there's an inversion here, but can't seem to find the correct definition of the 'OF'. In Webster's dictionary, def. 5b is "in respect to". This definition makes sense, but the example sentence given there is: "[he is] slow of speech". Can I invert a sentence like this? "Of speech, he is slow"? it sounds awkward.

*if I completely change the array of the misunderstood sentence, I can understand it perfectly:
"The variety of less frequent and perhaps unique deviations from the standard patterns is almost endless."
When I read it that way I feel like I'm inventing new magic grammar rules, since I'm not merely reversing the inversion here, but I'm planting the entire first clause between the parts of the second clause.

Can anyone help me with the grammar rules of this sentence?

Comment: *Of* serves to mean *having...deviations*. The construction is unusual and makes the sentence fancy, but it doesn't rely heavily on the opening *of*. You might say the inversion keeps the reader waiting.

Comment: Move _the variety_ to the beginning of the sentence. And delete the comma.

Comment: This is ponderous diction posing as elevated speech. Your reversal makes the sentence understandable, which should have been the writer's intention from the start.  Your version of the sentence is better.

Comment: Your definition of *of* is correct here, and your version changes the meaning. Try simplifying to see. Their version: *The parade is almost endless of [with respect to] elephants.* = *Of [with respect to] elephants, the parade is almost endless.* (This parade has a lot of elephants.) Your version: *The parade of elephants is almost endless.* (This is a parade of elephants, not a parade with elephants and other stuff.)

Comment: "I'm planting the entire first clause between the parts of the second clause." <- This is incorrect. There is only one clause. "Of . . . patterns" is a prepositional phrase. The author put it before its referent ("the variety"), which is unusual. By placing it after its referent, you are putting it in its "standard" place.

Comment: @JohnLawler : That makes a correct sentence, but one with a different meaning.

Comment: Do you see 'Of less frequent and perhaps unique deviations from the standard patterns, the variety is almost endless…' as complete in itself, or lacking context?

Comment: I've no idea why the OP is so upset about transforming the sentence. There's nothing odd with transforming "On the hill, he saw a dog" to "He saw a dog on the hill", and even "He saw on the hill a dog" would be possible particularly if you amended it to "He saw on the hill a dog barking and running in circles".

Answer (score 1):

The definition in play here is, from [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/of),

> of *preposition* (RESULT)
>
> **resulting from or having to do with:**
>
> *the joy of family*
>
> *the fear of failure*

So we understand,

> The variety **resulting from** less frequent and perhaps unique
> deviation from the standard patterns is almost endless.

The *of* phrase has been preposed (moved to the front of the clause) in order to connect to the topic of the previous discussion. Much like in the following,

> There are terrible **goals**, great **goals**, and all sorts of
> **goals** that sit somewhere in between, but it is rare for anyone to score a goal that is unlike any you have previously seen and any you
> might witness in the future. Of **goals** from throw-ins only two
> spring immediately to mind, both inevitably controversial. ([The
> Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/football/blog/2015/nov/27/the-joy-of-six-quickly-taken-set-pieces))

From the original source, [Security Analysis](https://archive.org/details/dli.ernet.7983/page/71/mode/2up) (1940) by Benjamin Graham and David Dodd, p.71-72, bolding mine:

> *Numerous **Deviations** from the Standard Patterns.* —However, almost
> every conceivable departure from the standard pattern can be found in
> greater or less profusion in the security markets of today. Of these
> the most frequent and important are identified by the following
> designations: *income* bonds; *convertible* bonds and preferred stocks;
> bonds and preferred stocks with *stock purchase warrants* attached;
> *participating* preferred stocks; common stocks with *preferential
> features*; *nonvoting* common stock. Of recent origin is the device of
> making bond interest or preferred dividends payable either in cash or
> in common stock at the holder's *option*. The *callable feature* now found
> in most bonds may also be termed a lesser departure from the standard
> provision of fixed maturity of principal.
>
> Of less frequent and perhaps unique **deviations** from the standard
> patterns, the variety is almost endless. We shall mention here only
> the glaring instance of Great Northern Railway Preferred Stock which
> for many years has been in all respects a plain common issue; and also
> the resort by Associated Gas and Electric Company to the insidious and
> highly objectionable device of bonds convertible into preferred stock
> *at the option of the company* — which are, therefore, not true bonds at
> all.

Answer (score -1):

There is no case of inversion, only the  possibility of a choice in the place of a *nonrestrictive modifier*, which one  must be taken  as "*of less frequent and perhaps unique deviations from the standard patterns*", that  is, a  complicated prepositional phrase.

Webster's definition, def. 5b,  "in respect to",  does  not  apply. The variety is issued from a process of deviation, so the following definition from the SOED is the right one.

> (**SOED**) **IV**  Of the  source or starting-point of action, emotion, etc. **7** Indicating the mental or non-material spring of  action, emotion, etc., or the cause, reason or ground of an action, occurrence, fact, feeling, etc.: out of, from, as an outcome, expression,  or consequence of. [since Old English].
>
> - *of one's own accord, of choice, of course, of necessity, of right, of one's  own (free) will, etc.; die of, perish of, etc.; savour of, smell of, taste of, etc.; sick of, weary of, etc.; ashamed of, afraid of, fearful of, etc.; glad of, proud of, vain of, etc.*

The reasoning of inversion producing "Of speech, he is slow" is not correct; this is so because  "slow" is an adjective and "variety" is a  noun. By  recognizing that this modification is nonrestrictive it can  be   seen that the two possibilities of placement of the modifier,  either  as a  postmodifier or as a premodifier result in the same meaning. Here, it  is convenient  to use premodification as the  modifying phrase is long.

- Of less frequent and perhaps unique deviations from the standard patterns, the variety is almost endless.
- The variety, of less frequent and perhaps unique deviations from the standard patterns, is almost endless.

Perhaps, an example with a shorter phrase will show this more clearly.

- The students, with this handicap,  couldn't succeed. (*nonrestrictive*)
- With this handicap, the students  couldn't succeed. (*nonrestrictive*)
- The students of poor  background  couldn't be accepted. (*restrictive*)
- <s>Of poor  background, the students  couldn't be accepted.</s> (*different  meaning*)

> - The variety of less frequent and perhaps unique deviations from the standard patterns is almost endless.
>
> This  is not a correct correspodence  because  by using it you single out this  variety as the unique one having this characteristic. This is not  so  in the initial sentence.

Comment: No. *The variety of less frequent and perhaps unique deviation from the standard patterns is almost endless* is perfectly good English. Here, [*variety*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/variety)  means *multifariousness* rather than *subtype*, as it does in the OP's sentence.